# How to export all the components with require?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, export

I'm making a Vue js application in which I need to export all the files / components from a certain directory and import those files / components them in a file i.e `path.js`.

How should I exports the components if I `require` them all in `index.js` so that I can access them in `path.js` as `import {Component1,Component2} from index.js`?

**Note**: *I don't want to explicitly include components in index.js with `import` keyword that is why I used `require`.*

**Index.js**

```js
import upperFirst from "lodash/upperFirst";
import camelCase from "lodash/camelCase";


const requireComponent = require.context(".", true, /\.vue$/); // used to fetch Component1.vue and Component2.vue
const components = {};


requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName);
  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(fileName.replace(/^\.\//, "").replace(/\.\w+$/, ""))
    );
  
  components[componentName] = requireComponent(fileName).default;
  
});
export default components;
```

**paths.js**

```js
import {Component1,Component2} from 'index.js';'

console.log(Component1); // undefined
```

I've tried exporting components as `export {...components}` but that throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

import Component from 'index.js'

As you exported it in just a single constant value.

Comment: But I want to import is as `import {Component1,Component2} from index.js`, so how should I export it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as Component1 or Component2 in Index.js, but I think I know what you are looking for.

You can achieve it through Named exports and imports.

Simple example below:

index.js

```
export {components[0] as Component1};
export {components[1] as Component2};

export default components;
```

paths.js

```
    import {Component1, Component2} from 'index.js';
    //some code
```

Comment: index.js fetches Component1 and Component2 by using the `require` keyword.

Comment: i updated my answer. i think components[0] refers to Component1, components[1] refers to Component2. let me know if you were able to use it.